# Operator overloading with generic function parameters

Tags: c#, generics, operator-overloading

I have a problem with operator resolution on generic methods.

From my understanding of section 7.3.4 of the spec within the function EqualOperatorGeneric (sample code below) the correct overload of the == operator on the type A should be found, but instead it seems to get the candidate for (object, object).

Am I doing something very obvious wrong? Is there a method to get the expected behaviour and if not can I turn the given case into a compile time or runtime error?

```
public class A
{
    public A(int num)
    {
        this.Value = num;
    }

    public int Value { get; private set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as A;
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null))
            return false;

        return Object.Equals(this.Value, other.Value);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public static bool operator ==(A l, A r)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(l, null))
        {
            return !Object.ReferenceEquals(r, null);
        }

        return l.Equals(r);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(A l, A r)
    {
        return !(l == r);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(EqualOperatorGeneric(new A(1), new A(1)));
    }

    public static bool EqualOperatorGeneric<L, R>(L l, R r)
        where L : class
        where R : class
    {
        return l == r;
    }
}
```

Output:

> False

Comment: You could easily cut out at least half of that code and still demonstrate the relevant principle, for clarity's sake.

Comment: I personally like repros to be a little verbose, but i could prolly remove the other equality checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After scrounging the spec I realized you can use the dynamic keyword to defer binding of the operator from compile time to runtime. This fixes the issues I have been having:

```
public static bool EqualOperatorGeneric<L, R>(L l, R r)
{
    dynamic dl = l, dr = r;
    return dl == dr;
}
```

Comment: I would very strongly advise you against doing this.  Rather than using a tool specifically designed to be statically bound and deferring the binding of the entire method's compilation until runtime, you should simply use an equality comparison tool that is inherently designed to not be bound when this generic method is compiled, specifically through the use of `object.Equals` or an `IEqualityComparer`.  In addition to not needing to re-compile the method every time you invoke it, this will continue to meet the expectations of callers of the method as it is more idiomatic of C#.

Comment: In the real world the use of comparison tool is not always decided by the actor that defined the equality logic for the objects in question. Dynamic dispatch is EXACTLY the right tool to use here for the case where the correct polymorphic behaviour cannot be determined at compile time. Your arguments of technical "pureness" are meaningless in the context of using programming language as a tool instead of as a toy.

Comment: Cases where the objects to be compared themselves do not define equality in a manor that you would hope for is exactly what `IEqualityComparer` is there for, and why it sounds like exactly the correct tool for this particular method.  You can trivially create an equality comparer that uses an object's `==` operator to perform its equality check, if that is the semantics you want and the object's `Equals` method has a different implementation.  Having said that, it is generally very poor practice for an object's `Equals` method an `==` operator to disagree on equality semantics.

Comment: You dont seem to understand the initial case. The objects to be compared define equality like required. Static binding CAUSED the semantics of .Equals and == to be different. Dynamic dispatch brings the correct (meaning as implemented by the object designer) behaviour. Your above comment makes no sense.

Comment: Assuming that each *Type* has defined equality sensibly, that is to say the `==` operator and the `Equals` method return the same values for the same objects (when the compile time type of the variables is the same as the run time type), then this effectively means that when actually performing an equality check you should use `Equals` for late binding an `==` for early binding.  You were using the wrong tool on the caller side, `==` instead of `Equals`, given that you want to have late binding. Using the early bound equality tool, `==`, and compiling the whole method late, is very roundabout.

Comment: Please reread what I wrote. The issue lays in the way that the designer of the objects and the consumer of the equality semantics are not the same person. If you like you can travel to all my customers and explain to them how them using an == operator for equality is them doing it wrong. The only helpful sentence you wrote on here was "Operator bound statically at compile time when in context of generic method" (and this was valuable info to me). Everything after that is just you trying to boost your ego for some unknown reason.

Comment: Using the `==` operator to define equality is not wrong.  Defining equality through the `==` operator *and having it be semantically different from the `Equals` method* is certainly non idiomatic, and likely going to result in confusion when using that type.  If you have a method that requires comparing objects for equality, I would *strongly* suggest accepting  `IEqualityComparer`.  It is entirely unambigious what the equality semantics are of such a method, as the caller defines them.  They need not guess whether they need to define `Equals`, `operator ==`, `IEquatable`, etc.

Comment: If you have one customer expecting a dynamically bound `==` operator to be used then doing this may help them, but what about every other customer that you have that *doesn't* expect that, as it's an entirely un-idiomatic approach for equality in C#.  Have you no consideration for all of them?

Answer (score 2):

When `EqualOperatorGeneric` is compiled the `==` operator needs to be bound statically, when the method is compiled, to a single implementation.  It is not bound separately for each separate usage of the generic method.

This is what differentiates generics from, say, C++ templates.  The generic method is compiled *once* and then applied to every usage with every set of type arguments, whereas templates are compiled separately for each set of generic arguments.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense (was thinking about this more from a C++ templates view) implementation wise. But does it not go directly against the wording of the spec? This is a repro of an incredibly nasty bug I have to deal with. It there any way to detect this scenario at compile time?

Comment: @MrDosu No, it doesn't go against the spec.  For the purposes of overload resolution, the types of the two operands to the operator are `object` and `object`, because when compiling the generic method the types could resolve to any type of object.  As for detecting it, what do you mean by that?  Detecting the use of operators within generic functions that have operands of a generic type?  That doesn't sound all that useful; you'd just see tons of correct usages of general purpose operators.

Comment: I guess "Determine the type of T" can be interpreted a multitude of ways and in this instance of compile once generics object is the logical answer. Still pragmatically this means that == operators are fundamentally broken in generics.

Comment: @MrDosu No, they're not fundamentally broken, they just work fundamentally differently than you expect.  They work exactly as they were designed to work.  Your expecting generic operations to be dynamically compiled, and they aren't.  Your fundamental understanding of generics is simply wrong.

Comment: If they work fundamentally differently in a certain scenario and change the semantics of equality in a clearly defined class I would pragmatically call that broken. Technically you might call that a beautiful feature of the language, you must a agree its very low on the usefulness scale. Semantics.

Comment: @MrDosu They *don't* work fundamentally differently.  They work exactly the same as they do anywhere else.  The types of the operands are evaluated when the expression is compiled, and a specific implementation of the operator is bound at that time.  That's exactly what happens anywhere else you use the operator.  I don't agree that it's not useful.  It's certainly useful.  Just because it doesn't work the way that you want it to doesn't make it wrong, and it's not like you don't have entirely appropriate mechanisms to accomplish what you *do* want to do, this just isn't the right mechanism.

Comment: I agree with you technically. It works fundamentally different semantically for the defined class independently of language. Compile once is all you needed to mention to get whats going on in a language with overloaded static operators and no late static binding. It has nothing to do with what I want, but what is reasonable to expect. We are just argueing at this point and should just stop because I cant fathom a case where "== operator defaults to Object.ReferenceEquals for all invocations" can ever be considered useful.